# How can I realize this matrix product (dot product of matrices of different orders)?

Tags: matrix, tensors

The matrix multiplication of square matrices of different order is often claimed to be impossible. Yet, if the order of one matrix is divisible by the order of the other, a natural multiplication rule is visible. The bigger matrix simply should be considered a "matrix of matrices" or, alternatively, in small matrix all elements should be replaced with equivalent diagonal $m\times m$ (in this case, $2\times2$) square matrices:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_2} & {d_2} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_3} & {b_3} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 {a_1} & {b_1} & {a_2} & {b_2} \\
 {c_1} & {d_1} & {c_2} & {d_2} \\
 {a_3} & {b_3} & {a_4} & {b_4} \\
 {c_3} & {d_3} & {c_4} & {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$
$=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a {a_1}+{a_3} b & a {b_1}+b {b_3} \\
 a {c_1}+b {c_3} & a {d_1}+b {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a {a_2}+{a_4} b & a {b_2}+b {b_4} \\
 a {c_2}+b {c_4} & a {d_2}+b {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_1} c+{a_3} d & {b_1} c+{b_3} d \\
 c {c_1}+{c_3} d & c {d_1}+d {d_3} \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 {a_2} c+{a_4} d & {b_2} c+{b_4} d \\
 c {c_2}+{c_4} d & c {d_2}+d {d_4} \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$

So, in certain circumstances this is possible. People on [Math.Stackexchange commented](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483224/is-there-any-reasonable-proposal-on-multiplication-of-square-matrices-of-differe?noredirect=1) that this is essentially tensor product, but `TensorProduct` in Mathematica gives something different.

So, can such product be somehow realized in Mathematica? Maybe I shoud use TensorProduct in some combination with other transformation?

Also, is there a way to "expand" the matrix increasing its order this way:
$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

That is to an equivalent matrix of higher order (replace all elements with equivalent matrices)?

Comment: It looks to me you just want to take the Kronecker product of the smaller matrix with an appropriately-sized identity matrix, e.g. `KroneckerProduct[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, IdentityMatrix[2]]`.

Comment: @J.M. well, this looks like a first step, yes. I just wanted to ask a separate question on how to expand a matrix this way.

Comment: @J.M. I wonder whethwer there is an opposite operation that would shrink the matrix on this pattern? And, also, optionally shrink a matrix of the pattern $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 -b & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$ to a complex number.

Comment: @J.M. I made a complete solution to the question based on your advice. See my answer, thanks!

Comment: Your question about the "opposite operation" should perhaps be a separate question altogether.

Comment: @J.M. yes: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270178/how-to-make-an-inverse-operation-to-kroneckerproducta-identitymatrixm-si/270180?noredirect=1

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the hint of @J.M.'sslightlylessbusy I made the code:

```
DotG[A_, B_] := 
 KroneckerProduct[A, 
   IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[A]]] . 
  KroneckerProduct[B, 
   IdentityMatrix[LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]/Length[B]]]
```

This can multiply square matrices of any orders!

Comment: Since your matrices are assumed square, 1. you can use `SquareMatrixQ[]` as an argument check; and 2. you can use `Length[]` to get the dimension. You might also consider computing the `LCM[]` only once.

Comment: @J.M. thanks! $\phantom{}$

Comment: @J.M. only once - this way? `KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[l/Length[A]]] . KroneckerProduct[B, IdentityMatrix[l/Length[B]]] /. l -> LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]`

Comment: Well, that's what `Module[]` is useful for: `DotG[A_?SquareMatrixQ, B_?SquareMatrixQ] := Module[{na = Length[A], nb = Length[A], lc}, l = LCM[na, nb]; (* stuff *)]`

Comment: @J.M., thanks! But this would be a bit longer.

Comment: It's up to you, but what you have is already a little long and confusing due to repeated things.

Comment: @J.M. is it possible to define it so it to fall back tot he dot product for non-square matrices?

Comment: That's what an `If[]` can be used for, of course.

Comment: @J.M. well, it seems that defining the function with SquareMatrixQ does not affect the previous definitions for other arguments. Thus, `DotG[A_, B_]:=Dot[A, B];
DotG[A_?SquareMatrixQ, B_?SquareMatrixQ]:=KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[l/Length[A]]] . KroneckerProduct[B, IdentityMatrix[l/Length[B]]] /.l -> LCM[Length[A], Length[B]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using ReplaceAll:

We first create a matrix of matrices and flatten this:

```
m1 = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
m2 = m1 /. {x_?(MemberQ[{a, b, c, d}, #] &) :> {{x, 0}, {0, 
      x}}}; m2 // MatrixForm
(m3 = ArrayFlatten[m2]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Then we do the same using indexed matrix elements:

```
fun[j_] = 
  m1 /. {x_?(MemberQ[{a, b, c, d}, #] &) :> (Subscript[x, j] )};
(m4 = {{fun[1], fun[2]}, {fun[3], fun[4]}}) // MatrixForm
(m5 = ArrayFlatten[m4]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Finally we multiply the matrices and partition them into the required form:

```
(m6 = m3 . m5) // MatrixForm
(m7 = Partition[m6, {2, 2}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: KronekerProduct (as @J.M. advised) makes the "matrix of matrices" easier. See my answer to this question, it gives a complete solution for this kind of multiplication for any orders (yours works only for one order combination). For instance, one can multiply $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

A simple matrix product seems to do the trick.

```
A = {{a, b},
     {c, d}};
B = {{{{a1, b1}, {c1, d1}}, {{a2, b2}, {c2, d2}}},
     {{{a3, b3}, {c3, d3}}, {{a4, b4}, {c4, d4}}}};
```

In the front end these matrices look like you want:

```
A // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
B // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_1 & b_1 \\
 c_1 & d_1 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_2 & b_2 \\
 c_2 & d_2 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_3 & b_3 \\
 c_3 & d_3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_4 & b_4 \\
 c_4 & d_4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Just matrix-multiplying them with [`Dot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) does what you need:

```
A . B // MatrixForm
```

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a a_1+a_3 b & a b_1+b b_3 \\
 a c_1+b c_3 & a d_1+b d_3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a a_2+a_4 b & a b_2+b b_4 \\
 a c_2+b c_4 & a d_2+b d_4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_1 c+a_3 d & b_1 c+b_3 d \\
 c c_1+c_3 d & c d_1+d d_3 \\
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a_2 c+a_4 d & b_2 c+b_4 d \\
 c c_2+c_4 d & c d_2+d d_4 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: This question is already answered, see my own answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: If simple matrix product did the trick, there would be no need for the question.

Comment: Multiply an order 2 matrix (2 x 2) and order 3 matrix (3 x 3) using your method.

Comment: Maybe give some more examples? The one example you gave is calculated with a simple dot product, and I don't know what you mean by multiplying 2x2 with 3x3.

Comment: $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
 -2 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ See the code in my answer and try it.