# How to make an inverse operation to `KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[m]]` (simplify matrix)?

Tags: matrix, tensors

The operation `KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[m]]` expands the matrix `A` in the following way (depending on order of `A` and `m`):

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Is there a way to code the inverse operation that would shrink ("simplify") a matrix this way?

Like

$ \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & b \\
 c & 0 & d & 0 \\
 0 & c & 0 & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\to\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

and

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & 0 & 0 \\
 c & d & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & a & b \\
 0 & 0 & c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

I also would like if it could (optionally) shrink the matrices using complex numbers this way:

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & b & f & e \\
 -b & a & -e & f \\
 g & h & d & c \\
 -h & g & -c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)\to \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a+i b & f+i e \\
 g+i h & d+i c \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Of course, not all matrices would be shrinkable.

Comment: For the first question: Does `B[[1;;;;m,1;;;;m]]` do what you want?

Comment: `B = KroneckerProduct[A, IdentityMatrix[m]]` of course.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher well, for $\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & c & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & c \\
 d & 0 & b & 0 \\
 0 & d & 0 & b \\
\end{array}
\right)$ it returns `{{a}}`...

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 Mathematice code of a matrix does not look good for understanding.

Comment: As noted, one includes code so people can copy it into their own *Mathematica* sessions, instead of forcing them to retype everything.

Comment: "A instead of B" and "A instead of just B" have distinct meanings, the latter including the alternative "both A and B." I wasn't suggesting the former.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
m={{a,0,b,0},{0,a,0,b},{c,0,d,0},{0,c,0,d}};
1/2*TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{2,2,2,2}],{2,4}]
```

or

```
m={{a,b,0,0},{c,d,0,0},{0,0,a,b},{0,0,c,d}};
1/2*TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{2,2,2,2}],{1,3}]
```

This is related to [the partial trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_trace).

**Edit.** Here is very simple code to automatically decide whether to apply one or the other reduction. It is currently only for a fixed value of `dim` for simplicity:

```
dim=2;
traceLeft[m_]:=TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{dim,dim,dim,dim}],{2,4}];
traceRight[m_]:=TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{dim,dim,dim,dim}],{1,3}];
multipleOfIdentityQ[m_]:=MatchQ[Simplify[m-1/dim*Tr[m]*IdentityMatrix[dim]],{{0...}...}];
undo[m_]:=With[{mL=traceLeft[m],mR=traceRight[m]},
            Which[
               multipleOfIdentityQ[mL],1/dim*mR,
               multipleOfIdentityQ[mR],1/dim*mL,
               True,"Failed"]];
```

Both

```
undo[{{a,0,b,0},{0,a,0,b},{c,0,d,0},{0,c,0,d}}]
undo[{{a,b,0,0},{c,d,0,0},{0,0,a,b},{0,0,c,d}}]
```

return `{{a,b},{c,d}}`.

**Edit 2.** Here is another version that can deal with different dimensions. The code it not meant to be bombproof. Please `Clear` all previous definitions before using this:

```
traceLeft[m_,{dL_,dR_}]:=TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{dL,dR,dL,dR}],{1,3}];
traceRight[m_,{dL_,dR_}]:=TensorContract[ArrayReshape[m,{dL,dR,dL,dR}],{2,4}];
multipleOfIdentityQ[m_]:=And[SquareMatrixQ[m],With[{d=Length[m]},MatchQ[Simplify[m-1/d*Tr[m]*IdentityMatrix[d]],{{0...}...}]]];
undo[m_?SquareMatrixQ,d:{dL_,dR_}]:=With[{mL=traceLeft[m,d],mR=traceRight[m,d]},
               Which[multipleOfIdentityQ[mL],1/dR*mR,
                     multipleOfIdentityQ[mR],1/dL*mL,
                     True,"Failed"]];
undo[m_?SquareMatrixQ]:=With[{d=Length[m]},DeleteCases[Map[undo[m,{#,d/#}]&,DeleteCases[Divisors[d],1|d]],"Failed"]//If[#==={},"Failed",First[#]]&];
```

I suggest the following examples to see what this does (and what it does not do):

```
KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[5],Array[a,{4,4}]]//undo
KroneckerProduct[Array[a,{4,4}],IdentityMatrix[7]]//undo
KroneckerProduct[Array[a,{4,4}],Array[b,{2,2}]]//undo
KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[5],IdentityMatrix[4]]//undo
```

Note in particular that the last example returns neither `IdentityMatrix[5]` nor `IdentityMatrix[4]` but

```
{{1,0},{0,1}}
```

The specification is simply ambiguous in this sense. If one knows what dimensions one is interested in, one can directly call `undo[m_,d:{dL_,dR_}]`.

Comment: But how to make it to figure out, which ways to simplify matrix will work?

Comment: also, make it work for any order...

Comment: A $4\times4$ matrix can be simplified in two ways if we do not use complex or split-complex numbers. But for higher order it would be a greater number of ways.

Comment: Sure, that depends on the application, often one will know what the dimensions are. If you want to automate that, if `Dimensions[m] == {n,n}` then one can use `Divisors[n]` to find all the possible ways of splitting `n`. Why not try yourself and post a solution?

Comment: And where those divisors should be put?